# Update "let's encrypt" certificate from command line

Tags: raspberry-pi, letsencrypt

A raspberry pi 3B+ is outfitted with NextCloudPi.  Duckdns was setup and runs: the certificate expired August 13, 2023.

[image]

Is there a terminal command that can force certificate renewal?

I did find [certbot](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-forcefully-renew-lets-encrypt-certificate/):

```
certbot renew --force-renewal
```

I tried:

pi@nextcloudpi:~ $ `sudo certbot certonly`

Which returned:

> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>
> - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:    /etc/letsencrypt/live/downwind.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem    Your key
>   file has been saved at:
>   /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxx.duckdns.org/privkey.pem    Your cert
>   will expire on 2024-01-30. To obtain a new or tweaked    version of
>   this certificate in the future, simply run certbot    again. To
>   non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run    "certbot
>   renew"

Answer (score 2):

yeah, `certbot renew` is the way to go. Do it without `--force`-anything. If the certificate isn't due for a renewal, it isn't due.

Don't know what Linux distro "NextcloudPi" (never heard of that) is based on. Chances are, the `certbot` package came with a timer that you just have to activate to do these renewals automatically. Check whether `systemctl enable --now certbot.timer` reports success; if it did, congratulations, your certbot installation came with a timer for auto-renewal that you just had to activate!

If your certbot did not come with a timer, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/744633/how-to-install-certbot-via-snap-on-amazon-linux-2023/744641#744641) answer describes how to add your own and activate it, so that your certifcates never expire.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful reply.   I think NextCloutPi is a Debian distro for Raspberry Pi.

Comment: If you are curious, you can try. wget https://downwind.duckdns.org

Comment: Nextcloud is a Google Drive / OneDrive type cloud storage implementation, where the cloud part is actually on one's own hardware. I assume that NextcloudPi is a dedicated custom implementation

Comment: @gatorback if it's debian, then the `certbot` package most definitely [comes with `certbot.timer`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/all/certbot/filelist)